# How can I get the last 1000 messages sent by a certain user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've tried `channel.fetchMessages()`, but the limit is 100 messages. It's for a bot supposed to simulate users using machine learning.

Comment: Repeat the fetch call a further 99 times?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's API spam and it would just keep getting the same messages

Comment: To get a lot of messages you indeed just fetch messages again and again and again while respecting the rate limits. And you can't fetch just messages from a single user, you'll just fetch all messages in the channel and filter out the ones that aren't from the user you wish. Realistically you just want to fetch all the messages in the channel once, and store them in a database from where you'll pull.

Comment: the fetchMessages method just gives the last 100 messages, i think you're mixing up this with 'How to delete the last 1000 times', in which case it'll work because the last 100 messages will keep changing

Comment: Just get the ID of the last message you fetched and set it to the `before` property of a new `ChannelLogsQueryOptions` object and give it to `MessageManager.fetch()`. [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch).

Comment: so channel.fetchMessages({limit:100, before:lastmsg.id})?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The limit of returned messages is `100`, with the default being `50`. See the actual [API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages) for details.

By default, you get the *most recent* messages, but you can specify additional [query criteria](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions) when [fetching messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch). You'll need to repeat your fetch requests, adjusting the query criteria each time, in order to collect successively older messages. After each request, you can analyze what you've collected so far to determine if you need to keep fetching or not.

Beware of the [rate limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits).

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account what @jsejcksn is mentioning about the rate limits and how you can fetch the channel messages, here is a working implementation of it:

| Example Implementation | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70426769) |
| --- | --- |

```js
let messagesCounter = 0;
const channel = await findChannel(discordClient);
// Channel messages are limited up to 100 messages per request.
const channelMessages = await getMessages(discordClient, channel.id);
// Accumulate fetched messages
let fetchedMessages = channelMessages;
// Fetch discord until you get MAX_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES (1000)
let newMessages = channelMessages;
// If messages are returned, keep getting more until having 1000 messages
while (newMessages.length && messagesCounter < MAX_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES) {
  // Keep a counter to prevent an infinite loop
  messagesCounter += channelMessages.length;
  // Using the before filter, you can get oldest messages by using the last returned message
  const oldestMessage = newMessages[channelMessages.length - 1];
  newMessages = await getMessages(discordClient, channel.id, oldestMessage.id);
  fetchedMessages = fetchedMessages.concat(newMessages);
}
// Return all the channel messages (up to 1000 messages!)
ctx.body = `There are ${fetchedMessages.length} messages in the ${DISCORD_CHANNEL_NAME} channel`;
```

Based on the returned messages, you can easily filter by user id